# How can I center an image within SVG?

Tags: svg

I'd like to display an image of arbitrary aspect ratio in the center of an SVG tree that's relatively sized (all sizes are percentages).

The image is to be loaded dynamically, so the image size, i.e. aspect ratio, is unknown.

#### Examples:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

How do I do that without amending the image position in SVG with every image?

#### My SVG So Far

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#e44" />
    <image href="./image.png" width="68%" />
</svg>
```

Comment: The best  I can figure out is to use a percentage on the image's x/y and width/height, with x assigned the value of (100%-width%)/2 and y assigned the value of (100%-height%)/2 - as in: `<image x="16%" y="5%" href="./image.png" width="68%" height="90%" />`  Not really the solution I would like to find.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I cannot use `width` _and_ ´height` without distorting images with different aspect ratio (e.g. cropped images).

Comment: Do you have proof the image gets distorted?  The test I've done seems to show the image stays proportional and centered, even when width percentage is notably different from height percentage, as long as x is half the percentage removed from the width and y is half the percentage removed from the height

Comment: Oh gee, yes, my fault! Sorry! … In the documentation on MDN I couldn't find that images keep their aspect ratio by default.

Comment: @Darin: Your answer is the most simple and straightforward of them all. Would you want to convert your comment into an answer? I would happily mark that as an answer.

Comment: Added an answer, and glad this is working for you.  It seems all documentation is either lacking, or that little gold nugget of info you want is so buried in some hidden page that is hard to ever find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure the context you are using the svg in, but here is what worked for me.

Placed the following HTML file in same folder as image.png, opened in Brave browsers on Windows and it produced a near match to the upper image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <svg version="1.1" id="svg-layer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="280.0px" height="425.0px" viewbox="0 0 280.0 425.0">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#e44" />
        <image x="12%" y="5%" href="./image.png" width="76%" height="90%" />
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Placed following HTML file in same folder as image.png, opened in Brave browsers on in Windows and it produced a near match to the lower image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <svg version="1.1" id="svg-layer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="425.0px" height="280.0px" viewbox="0 0 425.0 280.0">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#e44" />
        <image x="12%" y="5%" href="./image.png" width="76%" height="90%" />
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not finding documentation explaining the behavior, but it appears that you only need to balance the x position to half of the percentage removed from the width, similarly, you only need to balance the y position to half of the percentage removed from the height.  The following 2 paragraphs explain the procedure used in these example.

The width of 76% was arbitrarily chosen, and the calculation to find x for the image was to subtract 76% from 100%, getting 24%, then divide the 24% by 2, giving 12% for final value of x.

The height of 90% was arbitrarily chosen, and the calculation to find y for the image was to subtract 90% from 100%, getting 10%, then divide the 10% by 2, giving 5% for final value of y.

Even though I'm using different percentages for width and height, the image didn't seem to distort in any of the test I tried.

If anyone knows where the docs for this behavior, please include them in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a native JavaScript Web Component (support in all modern browsers)

  - load the image,
  - in the `onload` event process its width and height in the DOM
  - calculate its center position; or let `animateMotion` do the work
  - *replace* the loaded IMG with SVG
  - inside a shadowDOM so SVG ID values do not conflict with each other
- shadowDOM can be styled with standard `part` attributes

Then all required HTML is:

```html
<svg-centered-image href="https://picsum.photos/id/7/140"></svg-centered-image>
<svg-centered-image href="https://picsum.photos/id/7/140/70"></svg-centered-image>
<svg-centered-image href="https://picsum.photos/id/7/170/60"></svg-centered-image>
```

To display:

[image]

**All code required:**

Load it once, doesn't matter when, all existing HTML tags will automagically upgrade:

```html
<style>
  svg-centered-image {
    width: 180px;
    height:180px;
    background: pink;
    display: none;
  }
  svg-centered-image::part(image){
    outline:5px solid black;
  }
</style>

<svg-centered-image href="https://picsum.photos/id/7/140"></svg-centered-image>
<svg-centered-image href="https://picsum.photos/id/7/140/70"></svg-centered-image>
<svg-centered-image href="https://picsum.photos/id/7/170/60"></svg-centered-image>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-centered-image", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let href = this.getAttribute("href");
      this.attachShadow({mode:"open"}).append(
        Object.assign(document.createElement("img"), {
          src: href,
          onload: (evt) => {
            let {width,height} = evt.target;
            this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = 
                `<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="background:pink" >
                 <image part="image">
                  <animateMotion dur="0.001s" fill="freeze">
                    <mpath href="#centerPoint" />
                  </animateMotion>
                 </image>
                 <path id="centerPoint" d="M100,100"/>
              </svg>`;
            let image = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("image");
            image.setAttribute("href", href);
            image.setAttribute("x", ~~width / -2);
            image.setAttribute("y", ~~height / -2);
            this.style.display = "inline-block";
          }
        })
      );
    }
  })

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also apply `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` to the `<image>` element and set its width and height to 100%;

`preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` has a similar effect as [css `object-fit:contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) – the image will be fitted into the available space, preserving the aspect ratio while showing the complete image.

```css
.resize {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<p>Resize me</p>
<div class="resize">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50%" height="100%" style="background:#e44; padding:1em">
    <image x="0" y="0" href="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" />
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="resize">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="500" style="background:#e44; padding:2em">
    <image x="0" y="0" href="https://picsum.photos/id/237/500/250" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Further reading:**
css-tricks: ["How to Scale SVG - by Amelia Bellamy-Royds"](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)